# Is there a .NET 6 equivalent System.Console assembly

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-6.0

On NuGet.org there is only a very old `System.Console` package targeting `.NET Framework 4.6` but no one for `.NET 6`.

Is this last version 4.3.1 from 2018 still valid for `.NET 6` or is it part of another assembly?

Comment: I've never had to manually install that - not sure if it is something dotnet includes  behinds the scenes.

Also, it looks to be compatible with .net6: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Console#supportedframeworks-body-tab

Comment: Why do you think you need it in the first place? .NET 6 comes with support for `System.Console` out of the box. The package is a .NET Standard compatibility package; .NET 6 has no need for it (even though it's technically compatible, by virtue of being .NET Standard).

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Console#supportedframeworks-body-tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Console` is built into the base framework for any project targetting `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` in .NET 6 & 7 (and probably back to at least 3.1, but don't have anything open to check).

You don't need any additional dependencies for console output.

Answer (score 0):

It is a valid version but there is no need to install it explicitly  because corresponding namespaces and types come with BCL and should be available for projects build via SDKs like `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`. It seems that the package was introduced for [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-1) support.